# Is there anyway we can update the view in C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to update a text field,which populates a default value. But when I try to do so,even if I am able to change its value,when I leave the text field,its giving me the default value only.
For ex: The default value is populated as 100,but if I try to edit it to 98, then when I leave the text field its again 100

I tried to update the UpdateView,but it doesn't work.It didn't throw any error.

```
public override void UpdateView()
        {
            //ApplyCouponVal();
            base.UpdateView();
            if (this._couponControl.ReadOnly)
            this._couponControl.ReadOnly = false;
        Apply();

    }
 private void _couponControl_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ApplyCouponVal();
    }

  private void ApplyCouponVal()
    {
        double dCou = Convert.ToDouble(this._couponControl.Text);
        double dCou1 = dCou/1000;
        string oStr1 = dCou1.ToString();
        string oStr2 = this._couponControl.DataLink;           
        ModelSetData(this._couponControl.DataLink, oStr1);
    }
}
```

The value should be the user input.If user didn't input anything then,the value should be default.

Comment: Can you provide whole class and explain more where you using it? Is it forms?

Comment: you can also use client side libraries like jquery to update that textbox value dynamically.It is pretty easier to do this using jquery. IF you can.